# Insert After Last Item by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

This is my all script, I know this is long, but just one line is important and I add all it for insurance:

```
//Add new Addable div
$('.AddNewE').click(function () {

    var RemoveAddableButton = $('<input type="button" class="RemoveE button red" value="remove" />');

    $(RemoveAddableButton).click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.Addable').remove();
    });


    var TargetId = $(this).attr('id');
    TargetId = TargetId.substring(3);
    var Target = $('.Addable#' + TargetId + ':first');
    var Count = $('.Addable#' + TargetId).size();
    var CloneTarget = $(Target).clone();
    CloneTarget.find('input').val('');
    CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable#' + TargetId + ':last'); // ***importantOne
    var TargetName = $(Target).find('input').attr('name');


    if (Count == 1) {

        var CloneName = TargetName + '[1]';
        TargetName = TargetName + '[0]';

        $(Target).find('input').attr('name', TargetName);
        $(Target).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', TargetName);
        $(CloneTarget).find('input').attr('name', CloneName);
        $(CloneTarget).append($(RemoveAddableButton));

        if ($(CloneTarget).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').size() > 0) {
            $(CloneTarget).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').remove();
            $(CloneTarget).append(
                        $('<span class="field-validation-valid invalid-side-note" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="' + CloneName + '"></span>')
            );
        }


    } else {

        var indx = TargetName.length - 3;
        var CloneTargetName = TargetName.substring(0, indx);
        CloneTargetName = CloneTargetName + '[' + Count + ']';
        $(CloneTarget).find('input').attr('name', CloneTargetName);
        $(CloneTarget).append($(RemoveAddableButton));

        if ($(CloneTarget).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').size() > 0) {

            $(CloneTarget).find('span[class*="field-validation"]').remove();
            $(CloneTarget).append(
                        $('<span class="field-validation-valid invalid-side-note" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="' + CloneTargetName + '"></span>')
            );

        }

    }



    (function ($) {
        $.fn.updateValidation = function () {
            var form = this.closest("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
            return this;
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $(Target).updateValidation();
    $(CloneTarget).updateValidation();



});
```

If I click the `.AddNewE` button then a new `div` added, but as my script I want to add this new `div` to the end of the `divs` so I use

```
CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable#' + TargetId + ':last');
```

but always the new `div` added as a second `div` it means always the `:first` and `:last` div is same and is first one also I checked by:

```
$('.Addable#' + TargetId).css('border', '');
    $('.Addable#' + TargetId + ':last').css('border', '3px dotted green');
    $('.Addable#' + TargetId + ':first').css('border', '3px dotted red');
```

So where is the problem? why the jQuery can't recognize last `div` ?

Comment: If you use ID JQuery takes only the first even you have some element with the same ID.

Comment: @Hadas But I don't have another choise, in some time I have 2 different Add Button with two different `div`s or more, so how can I handle it without Id?

Comment: multiple ID is not valid, so you'll have to use a class if you want more than one.

Comment: Add class to all the targets in the '.Addable'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the jQuery selector: $('.Addable#' + TargetId + ':last')

It is not valid HTML when you have multiple elements with the same id (#TargetId). ID is unique and you're not supposed to have more than 1 element with the same ID.

The jQuery selector assumes you use valid correct HTML markups, so it doesn't bother to collect all your elements with that ID. As soon as jQuery found the first element in the DOM with that ID, it stops and appends your new element right after that.

Try updating your jQuery selectors to simply: $('.Addable:first') and $('.Addable:last') and see if it works.